# actiuon script 3 default constructor explanation

Tags: actionscript-3, constructor, default

i get a duplicate declaration for these constructors, do the default constructor gets class as default.... some one knows the answer?

```
public function GraphNodeStyle() {
    super(CollapsibleNodeStyleComponent);
}

public function GraphNodeStyle(componentClass:Class) {
    super(componentClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one constructor in ActionScript.  Use an `initializeWithComponentClass()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default value for your constructor and depends on the value call the `super` with the right parameter:

If you are interesting in differentiate `new GraphNodeStyle(null)` than `new GraphNodeStyle()` :

```
class GraphNodeStyle extends ... {
    function GraphNodeStyle(componentClass:Class=null) {
        super((componentClass===null)?CollapsibleNodeStyleComponent:componentClass);
    }
}
```

otherwise you can use `*` as type to accept undefined value so ou can differentiate both case, of course you loose the type verifying from the compiler since you accept any value and not only Classes :

class GraphNodeStyle extends ... {

```
    function GraphNodeStyle(componentClass:*=undefined) {
        super((componentClass===undefined)?CollapsibleNodeStyleComponent:componentClass);
    }
}
```